# How many are some special gaps between primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-gaps

Gap primes are certainly even numbers.   (starting from the consecutive primes $3$ and $5$)
Let $n$ be however an **odd** number and define by $n^2$ the range of the examined primes ( i.e. the range is defined from $2$ to $n^2$)
Now I have examined gaps up to the value of  $71^2=5041$.

It seems that in all these ranges defined by $n^2$ there is **only one special  gap**  equal to $14$ which occurs in the special range up to $13^2$.
It is special because  $14$ is greater than $13$.
The gap is between numbers $113$ and $127$.
For others ranges defined by $n^2$ the maximal gap **is less** than $n$.

My question:

- Is the gap  between $113$ and $127$  unique for set of all primes,
  or however we can find the next such special gap with property described above?

  If not how to explain it?

Answer (score 2):

Using https://oeis.org/A000101 and https://oeis.org/A005250 , I did check that this seems the only such special gap. And looking at the trend in [image: this image], it doesn't look like there will be any other later too. This doesn't seem provable with the current results on prime gaps though (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds). We require $g_n < p_n^{0.5}$ to prove this, but the best we currently have is $g_n < p_n^{0.525}$

Comment: So we have, it seems, empirical evidence that prime gaps in the range up to $n^2$ after $113-127$ gap is limited by $n$. What is special with the case $113-127$ ? Maybe it is important that $11^2$ is between these two numbers..

Comment: Looking at the least prime factors of numbers between $114-126$ : $[2,5,2,3,2,7,2,11,2,3,2,5,2]$, I think it just happened to be very lucky that those multiples of $11(121), 7(119)$ and $5(115,125)$ happen to fit so snugly here without crossing each other out.If the multiple of $11$ were to fall at the same place of multiple of let's say $7$, then one of these numbers would have become prime

Comment: Yes, striking coincidence. Anyway thank you for the whole answer (empirical in its core) which has given me some additional ideas to think over.. maybe I'll place in near future some additional question concerning  this special number $11^2$ disrupting the general property for prime gaps.